# wordpress 3.1.1 Warning: call_user_func()

Tags: php, wordpress

i am building a plugin for wordpress version 3.3.1 , some resone my client want to this version,

i have this exception at this time : 
Warning: call_user_func() [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback in E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-3.1.1\wp-admin\includes\template.php on line 1160

here is inside the plugin :

```
<?php settings_fields(PLUGIN_SETTINGS); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections(PLUGIN_SETTINGS_SECTION); ?>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: So what is unclear in the error message for you?

Comment: Hello Zerkms Thanks for reply , in my case this error shown on older wordpress version not on new , if you know the reason please help me 
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to read the error message?

Comment: The problem with : 

add_settings_section('my_plugin_section', 'My Settings',  array( &$this,'mainSettings_callback'), 'myPluginsettings');

the "mainSettings_callback" function was missing :) in my plugin class.

Thanks,
Zerkms.

Comment: `&` in front of `$this` is redundant

Comment: Zerkms please explain , i did & because word-press do the same call the function inside the call if i am not wrong ? anyway my plugin work good :) with &

Comment: `&` is taking a reference, which isn't used in a function invocation (or with objects) in php for may be 10 years or so. So if you see someone using it with `$this` it means it's either 10 years old code or a person hasn't refreshed their knowledge for such a long period.

Comment: Thank You Zerkms i really appreciate for response